# Share data between two flutter apps in same mobile

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

**I want to share data between two flutter apps without share package that share data between apps when user select installed application, I want to send data to one app and fetch that data from the second application. How can I achieve this in flutter?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved required functionality by using **Content Providers** of android and call them natively in flutter using method channels. Now its working fine as I want to achieve.

you can learn more about Content Providers by visiting [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics) link.

**Note: I only want to achieve this for android not iOS.**

Comment: That's great. Don't forget to accept your own answer (the system may make you wait a few days, to allow others to answer). Accepting your answer will make it clear to others who read this question in future that it works.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica It is saying you can not vote to your own answer.

Comment: They must have changed that recently. It has been allowed until now - and encouraged because people are more likely to trust an accepted answer. It used to say that you cannot accept it for two days, to allow others to post; maybe that's it? In any case, I am glad that you found your answer. And thanks for sharing it and helping others

Answer (score 0):

If the apps are on the same device, then I would recommend an Sqlite databse.

If you do not want to do that, the use an HTTPS API.

- you can use a server to store the data and allow the aps to read & write it
- or, you can simply have the apps sent HTTPS requests to each other on `localhost` at a port of your choice, ***BUT***, that only works it the apps are on the same deveice. If they are on separate deveices then you must have a server

I cannot see any other option.

Comment: how can we access Sqlite database of one application from other application in flutter

Comment: Since only one can access it at any time, you would need to use a client/server model to avoid conflict. One app would "own" the database and the other would request aceess (by HTTPS API).